# About advertisement using reels

Tags: clothing, music

Assalamu alaikum i wanted to ask if it is haram to sell your brand clothes using a model and music
E.g to advertise my clothes i took a model, wore him the clothes and made a reel with a song and uploaded it. So is it haram to do that?